# asp.net C# -Serverside controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to clear the server side control textbox which is readonly set to true.

I used the jquery `$('#mycontrol').val('');`

textbox is cleared using this code.But the val property of textbox still have value,which appears in the textbox during postback,since `AutoPostBack = true` for this control.

Comment: Did you tried also $('#mycontrol').attr("value","");

Answer (score 2):

It may be because the server changes the control id when it renders it. You can access this id  with

```
$('#<%=mycontrol.ClientID%>')
```

You can also add `ClientIDMode=static` on the control to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If its a serverside control you can use jquery partial reference of ID

```
$('[id^="mycontrol"]').val("");
```